# Even After Specifying the error_bad_lines=False, getting the parser error in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, parsing

I am trying to read file using Pandas dataframe, space delimited, in order to skip the unwanted columns I am using `error_bad_lines=False`

However, Even after using the `error_bad_lines=False`, I am getting the parser Error after skipping as shown below

```
df = pd.read_csv("/Volumes/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/T.txt", delimiter=' ', header=None, error_bad_lines=False)
```

So, why I am still getting the parsar error, even after `error_bad_lines=False`?

```
1 fields, saw 85\nSkipping line 64251: expected 61 fields, saw 85\nSkipping line 64252: expected 61 fields, saw 85\nSkipping line 64253: expected 61 fields, saw 85\nSkipping line 64254: expected 61 fields, saw 85\nSkipping line 64255: expected 61 fields, saw 85\nSkipping line 64256: expected 61 fields, saw 85\nSkipping line 64257: expected 61 fields, saw 85\nSkipping line 64258: expected 61 fields, saw 85\nSkipping line 64259: expected 61 fields, saw 85\nSkipping line 64260: expected 61 fields, saw 85\nSkipping line 64261: expected 61 fields, saw 85\nSkipping line 64262: expected 61 fields, saw 85\n
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-2cb12c940fec> in <module>
      3 import pandas as pd
      4 
----> 5 df = pd.read_csv("/Volumes/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/T.txt", delimiter=' ', header=None, error_bad_lines=False)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    700                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    701 
--> 702         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    703 
    704     parser_f.__name__ = name

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    433 
    434     try:
--> 435         data = parser.read(nrows)
    436     finally:
    437         parser.close()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1137     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1138         nrows = _validate_integer('nrows', nrows)
-> 1139         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
   1140 
   1141         # May alter columns / col_dict

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1993     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1994         try:
-> 1995             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   1996         except StopIteration:
   1997             if self._first_chunk:

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data()

ParserError: Too many columns specified: expected 85 and found 61
```

Comment: better show what you have in data. maybe you should use something different to skip lines.

Comment: this option works correctly for me but I use small data and I don't use `ipython`  - maybe problem is only `ipython`